# How to store the variable of the clicked table cell and transfer it to another form?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have used ajax(xmlhttp) to do a filter for my table. Below are my codes for select2.php which is my php code for getting the table out from the database.

```
    <?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test1");
    $q= $_GET['q'];

    $v= $_GET['v'];



    $output = "<table border='5' id='info' align = 'center'>
                <tr>
                <th><Font SIZE=5>Name</th>
                <th><Font SIZE=5>Number</th>
                <th><Font SIZE=5>Status</th>
                </tr>";

     if($v == "" && $q == "" )
    {

        $sql = "SELECT Name, Number, Status FROM particulars";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
           $name = $row['Name'];
           $number = $row['Number'];
           $status = $row['Status'];

           $output .= "<tr height='50'> <td value='$name'  class='crmname'>$name</td>"
                   . "<td height='50'>$number</td>"
                   . "<td height='50'>$status</td>"
                   . "</tr>";   
        }
    }

    else
    {
        if($q == "")
        {
            $sql = "SELECT Name, Number, Status FROM particulars WHERE Name LIKE '%$v%'";
        }
        else
        {

            $sql = "SELECT Name, Number, Status FROM particulars where Name like '%$v%' and status = '$q'";

        }
                 and Status = '$q'"


        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

           $name = $row['Name'];
           $number = $row['Number'];
           $status = $row['Status'];

           $output .= "<tr height='50'> <td value='$name' class='crmname'>$name</td>"
                   . "<td height='50'>$number</td>"
                   . "<td height='50'>$status</td>"
                   . "</tr>";   
        }

    }

     $output.="</table>";
    echo $output;
    mysqli_close($connect);
    ?>
```

Next is my index.php form where it will show the ajax function.

```
 <script>
        function crmsearch(strings)
        {
            var b = strings;    
            var c = document.getElementById("status");
            var a = c.options[c.selectedIndex].text;



            if(b ==  null || b == "")
            {
                b = "";
            }

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
            {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } 
            else 
            {
        // code for IE6, IE5
                var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
                {
                    document.getElementById("inputtable").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                }
            };

            xmlhttp.open("GET","select2.php?q="+a+"&v="+b,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
```

These are my html codes for the textbox filter and dropdown box live search 
    
            
            CRM

```
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id ="search_text" style="float: right" placeholder="Name" onkeyup="crmsearch(this.value)" autocomplete="off"> 

            <select name='status' id='status' onchange="crmsearch(search_text.value)">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Interested">Interested</option>
                <option value="Not Interested">Not Interested</option>
            </select>
           <span  style="float: right; margin-right: 15px" class ="input-group-addon">Search</span> 
            <br>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Currently all my codes work except for my below code which is trying to click on the first column of the table (name) and get the name of the cell that i click. For example, if i click on 'Winson', i will store 'Winson' into a variable and send it to another form. I have tried the following codes but in vail.

```
<script>
var name;
        $(document).ready(function()
        {

        $('#info tr .crmname').click(function()
        {

            name = $(this).text();
            alert(name);
            window.location = 'CV.php?name=' + name;



        });
        });
</script>
```

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Wow, that's pretty old: `// code for IE6, IE5`

Comment: @IvankaTodorova What is an IE6, IE5 ??

Comment: @Timothy Ancient versions of Internet Explorer. A browser that the great Tutankhamun used back in his time.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova, woah those Egyptians sure are some techie people

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same element id for each row. This causes confusion to the DOM since the id should be unique. Change your #crmname to a class and then you can use a selector like:

```
$('#info tr.crmname').click(function()
```

You are also returning the text of the TR element when you should be returning the text of the first TD with the name. So put a class on the first TR like .name so you can do this in your function:

```
name = $('.name', this).text();
```

EDIT:
If you want the click on the TD element then put the crmname class there, but not as an id as I mention in the comments. So do this:

```
$('#info tr .crmname').click(function()
```

Second, is your function working at all? Can you just add an alert as the very first part of your function to be sure it's working? So:

```
$('#info tr .crmname').click(function()
{
    alert('debug');
});
```

Comment: I have realised that i placed the id for crmname wrongly. I have tried your method on using classes but it couldnt work. For now,  i have changed the id to <td> instead. But my table cell is still not clickable

Comment: The id should not go on the TD. You have HTML with multiple td elements all having the same id. How will jQuery know which TD you meant? Any elements that repeat should not use an id, but instead use a class.

Comment: ohhh.. I have updated the code. Do you mean like what i have written in the code? just like that?

Comment: from what i have edited, i still cant slick on the row.